# How to keep an element always in the center of the white space generated by clip path?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Situtation:** I am trying to make the div (contains a textbox and button) to be always in the center of the white space left after the design of clip path (as you can see in the image attached).

*knowing that clip path is based on percentage it keep changing when the webpage size change*

**ISSUE:** When the webpage size change, the element is no more centered!

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Check-in</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 id="title">MOUS AIRWAY | <span id="check-in">CHECK-IN</span></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="userInfo">
        <span id="tooltip">É neccessario inserire un codice <br>fiscale (16 caratteri).</span>
        <input type="text" id="codiceFiscale" placeholder="cf" oninput="CloseToolTip()">
        <button onclick="CheckIn()" id="checkIn">Check-in</button>
    </div>

    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
header{
    font-family: bebas;
    color: gold;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #00008B;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 30% 50%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
    z-index: -1;
}
#title{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    font-size: 60px;    
}
#check-in{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    color: white;
}
.userInfo{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -450px;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
button{
    width: 170px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #00008B;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #00008B;
    color: white;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
#codiceFiscale{
    width: 450px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #00008B;
}
#codiceFiscale:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #00008B;
}
```

P.S: i need a solution using only html, css or js. no jquery or bootstrap library.
Thanks!

Comment: Being that the rest of the page is in percentages .. I suggest using percentages for your positioning .. Possibly using a combination of `calc` with percentages ..

Comment: I'm not familiar with calc can you please provide the code you are talking about

Comment: [CALC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: I mean the code to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep content always in verticaly center like in my case. here is the solution i found. make it independently from **clip-path**, the solution was easiest than i was overthinking...just give it **position absolute**! and of course make sure it always in center by using **percentage**.

**SOLUTION:**

```
.userInfo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-0%,-50%);
    align-items: center;
}
```